# Refreshing UI every 10 s causing my app to freeze

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid

I've created simple application that is reading data from MSSQL database every few seconds and binding datagrid with rows from db (in case there are new items in db).
In fact two applications are being used, one of them is inserting some rows to database and this app is not part of topic, and another one is displaying that rows, so if I wanted to keep second app updated all the time I'm refreshing
datagrid every 10 sec to keep it updated, but sometimes it freezes and that is really bad.. now I will explain this by image:

[image]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

    public MainWindow()
    {

        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //First time app is runned I'm getting all orders from DB because I want to show some items if they exist, when app is started
            var ordersList = OrdersController.getAllOrders();

            //This code is used just to fill my collection with ordersList when app is started so I don't need to wait for 10 sec to databind it (look below method in timer)
            collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
            collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("OrderNo"));
            DataContext = collectionViewSource;


            //In this method I'm binding my datagrid with ordersList, and I'm repeating this task every 10 seconds
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(10));
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

}



void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Here I'm setting source to my collection/datagrid
        var ordersList = OrdersController.getAllOrders();
        collectionViewSource.Source = null;

        collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
        DataContext = collectionViewSource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

// Method located in my Controller: OrdersController
public static List<Orders> getAllOrders()
{
    DataServices.MyApp.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, DataServices.MyApp.Orders);
    var results = DataServices.MyApp.proc_Orders_GetAll().ToList();
    List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        LocalOrders lorders = new LocalOrders();

        lorders.Title = item.Title;
        lorders.Note = item.Note;
        lorders.Code = Convert.ToInt32(item.Code);
        lorders.CreatedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedAt);
        orders.Add(lorders);
    }
    return orders;
}
```

I guess solution to this is to apply asynchronous task but I'm not sure, because I'm begginer and I don't have idea how this might be solved? I don't have logic of how things should work so I could choose some better path.. So any kind of help would be aswesome!

THANKS A LOT!
CHEERS!

Comment: You are running your timer_Tick function without checking if it is already running. If that method takes 11 seconds to finish another one has already been started.

Comment: do you experience freezes if you replace OrdersController.getAllOrders() with a simple new List<Orders>() with some items in it? if getAllOrders is what freezes your UI, then you execute it in a task, and then once the task is over, you do the rest as untill now

Comment: Just a couple of side questions: how many rows are being retrieved every tick? Have you measured how long it takes for the query to be executed and return the rows to the client?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, every tick or everytime timer_Tick method is invoked?

Comment: What is interesting to know is how long it takes from the start of _tick until the rows are available in the UI

Answer (score 0):

The `Tick` event of a `DispatcherTimer` is raised on the UI thread which means that your application will be will be frozen during the time it takes to fetch the data from the `OrdersController`. You may try to execute the `getAllOrders()` on a background thread by starting a TPL task:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return OrdersController.getAllOrders();
    })
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ask.Exception.Message);

        }
        else
        {
            collectionViewSource.Source = task.Result;
            DataContext = collectionViewSource;
        }
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If it is setting the `Source` property of the `CollectionViewSource`, you will have to fetch less data or try to remove the `GroupDescriptions`. I am afraid using `GroupDescriptions` won't work very well when you are displaying a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Tick handler async, and perform the long running operation in a Task:

```
private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var ordersList = await Task.Run(() => OrdersController.getAllOrders());

        collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```